# Converting vector image to Quartz 2D code

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics, osx-leopard

Is it possible to convert a vector image into Quartz 2D code (mac) so that
image can be drawn programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Not easily, you would have to write all the code yourself to do this. You might like to have a look at the [Opacity image editor](http://likethought.com/opacity/), which allows you to generate images and export them as Quartz or Cocoa drawing code.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of vector image?

NSImage loads PDFs the same way it loads bitmaps.

NSImage is Quartz 2D drawing, but if you meant that you need a CGImage, NSImage in 10.6 has a method for getting one.  However, CGImage is explicitly bitmap based, unlike NSImage.  The parameters you pass to `-[NSImage CGImageForRect:context:hints:]` will determine how the art is rasterized.  It will be rasterized the same way it would be if drawing to the passed rect in the passed context.

Comment: vector image from illustrator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vector code http://www.vectorcodeapp.com to generate core graphics code, which you may use programmatically, or even use to generate postscripts.